# logback.xml is ignored in normal Java project

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

Apparently, no logging occurred in my Java project. `logback.xml` file is located in the classpath but apparantly ignored. No any errors about this file are reported.

JAR is attached following way (with maven):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

The following messages appear in console:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:MYREPO/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.5/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:MYREPO/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

Apparently, both jars are referred by single maven entry.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Get rid of it. `logback` already provides the classes you need.